# Webpack compile, watch, start nodejs in debug (--inspect) and chrome

Tags: node.js, webpack

I struggled a lot to find out a solution to have all-in-one webpack config that compiles, watches and starts nodejs in debug mode (--inspect) without success.

Today the best solution I found is to have webpack watching for changes/compile and nodemon for whatching the dist folder and restart nodejs.
Even with nodemon, the debug option seems not to be compatible with --inspect (chrome debugger do not find the nodemon debug in chrome://inspect!)

I tried, to start the server after the build, to use start-server-webpack-plugin which almost worked but once the server is started, any new changes triggers a compilation but not a restart of nodejs!

So, I would really appreciate if you know all in one solution without having to call a shell command that does that:

- List item
- Webpack Compile
- Watch for changes
- Start NodeJs in debug (--inspect)
- Start chrome debugger (auto reconnect when restart)

Comment: Think you're looking for: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/

Comment: nope, my server is a middleware server exposing a REST service + DB access, it does not serve HTML content. That's the issue :-(.

Answer (score 1):

I use concurrently and put the following in package.json

```
"start": "concurrently \"webpack --watch && nodemon --inspect ./build/server.js\""
```